# DashDB ArcGIS Online Integration

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, ibm-cloud-plugin

Is there a means of integrating the ArcGIS Maps to my BlueMix webapp and integrate it to DashDB?  I want to use the Map Layer in my web app and integrate it with DashDB. 
I understand there is a possibility of integrating dashDB with ArcGIS Desktop. Can this be done in a way that i can show the maps on my web app?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want to do in the following way:

1. Create map layers with ArcMap (or ArcGIS Pro) accessing and displaying data from a DashDB database
2. Publish the map layers to ArcGIS online
3. Consume the map layers using an esri [leaflet.js](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet) layer in the web/mobile app.

You may need to host the map layers on an ArcGIS server in case you want to display live data (in contrast to copy the data from the database).

There are other options to consume the data published at ArcGIS Online, e.g. the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you read this article? dashDB tables can be made to look like Esri geodatabases.
https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/dashdb/get/load-geospatial-data-into-dashdb-to-analyze-in-esri-arcgis/